# Where can I find information about the wns payload format for toast messages?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to extend our existing push message solution written in php to WindowsPhone apps using WNS.
I can get the token from MS and I can send toast messages, but they do not show the messages I send.
All I found about the payload is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221551.aspx

Here is the xml as far as I have been able to find.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">
    <wp:Toast>
        <wp:Text1>text string 1</wp:Text1>
        <wp:Text2>text string 2</wp:Text2>
    </wp:Toast>
</wp:Notification>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same xml as if you are creating a toast locally from the application. Here is a list of templates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761494.aspx
It should work for both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 XAML applications